# Why I don't have Web References on UWP?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I'm making an cross-platforms application and I have a problem. For my application, I must use Web Services, but the really name is Web References.

In my project Xamarin, I can add Web References only for the project Android and iOS like in this picture:

[image]

But when I want to do the same for the project UWP, I don't have the option to add WebReferences like in this picture:

[image]

If I want to add Web References for the project Windows, I have the same problem. How can I have Web References for UWP ?

Thank you for your help, 
Karim

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a **Service Reference** and go to **Compatibility** and add **Web Reference**.

Select '**Add Service Reference**', then a popup will appear. Click '**Advanced...**' (another popup will appear), then you can see the '**Add Web Reference**' at the bottom under the Compatibility.

Hope it helps!